# How to parse a soap message loaded from a file?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, soap

I need to parse a SOAP message I load from the disk, to the type of the generated proxy. WCF does it when it receives the message from the http server, so I should be able to do it from the disk.

I consume a webservice with WCF, I generated the proxy client from the remote WSDL.

Here is the XML structure I received from the network (it was logged with System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging) that I want to parse to the generated class CRResponse.:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns1="urn:PourtuIntf" xmlns:ns2="ns2:PourtuIntf-IPourtu">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <ns2:GetCRResponse>
         <return>
            <ResultCode>0</ResultCode>
            <CR>
               <Theme SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:ItemType[5]">
                  <item>
                     <Key/>
                     <Section SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:Section[3]">
...
```

When I call the operation 'GetCR' of the web service, the message is correctly converted to the WCF generated proxy client type GetCRResponse, but I don't knwo how WCF works and I need to parse the file from the disk.

I tried to parse the message that way:

```
  GetCRResponse body;
  using (var xmlReader =  XmlReader.Create("Requests\\CR.xml"))
  {
      Message m = Message.CreateMessage(xmlReader, int.MaxValue, MessageVersion.Soap11);
      body = m.GetBody<GetCRResponse>();
  }
```

In the GeyBody method this exception is raised:

`Expected element 'ActGetCRResponse' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Pourtu.PourtuClient'.. Detecting 'Element' with name 'ActGetCRResponse', namespace 'urn:PourtuIntf-IPourtu'`.

I tried using the SoapFormatter:

```
using ( FileStream fs = new FileStream("Requests\\CR.xml", FileMode.Open) )
{
    SoapFormatter formatter = new SoapFormatter();
    body = (ActGetCRResponse)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
}
```

..the Deserialize throws the following exception: Analysis error, no assembly associated to the xml key 'ns2 GetCRResponse'.

I cannot use the xml serializer to deserialize to GetCRResponse beceause of the attributes SOAP-ENC:arrayType that need to be interpreted by the soap serializer.

Comment: please post the link or entire content of CR.xml, thank you.

Comment: Here is the entire CR.xml : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8lnwwg7ed7tunmm/AAD286dN8BHUrF2YYvjbPruna?dl=0 and here is the full WSDL : https://www.dropbox.com/s/gbdd3w3th0lon04/IPlotiservice.wsdl?dl=0

Comment: @abreneliere I can deserialize the SOAP message into the ActGetCRResponse object via XmlSerializer if create a set of object classes based on the SOAP xml. If that would be helpful, I can provide that, if not no worries :) Using the proxy classes generated from the wsdl has yielded only errors or null objects.

Comment: Yes I need to parse to the proxy classes because I need to call an operation of the webservice with the file's data.

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

```
Message m = Message.CreateMessage(XmlReader.Create("C:\\testSvc\\login.xml"), int.MaxValue, MessageVersion.Soap11);
            SoapReflectionImporter importer = new SoapReflectionImporter(new SoapAttributeOverrides(), "urn:PlotiIntf-IPloti");
            XmlTypeMapping mapp = importer.ImportTypeMapping(typeof(ActGetCRResponse));
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(mapp); 
            var o = (ActGetCRResponse)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(m.GetReaderAtBodyContents());
```

[reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3f02fa28-0450-40f1-9536-986709670707/xmlserializer-and-soaprpc-encoding?forum=asmxandxml)

Comment: Thank you for help, but the XmlSerializer does not understand SOAP-ENC:arrayType in order to parse the content of the element to the correct type.

Comment: @abreneliere have you tried using the `DataContractSerializer`?

Comment: Yes I added another post for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43741674/how-to-use-the-datacontractserializer-to-deserialize-a-wcf-soap-response-message?noredirect=1#comment74539944_43741674

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `XmlSerializer` to accomplish this with help of [`SoapReflectionImporter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5wt2he6(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var importer = new SoapReflectionImporter("ns2:PourtuIntf-IPourtu");
var mapping = importer.ImportTypeMapping(typeof(GetCRResponse));
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(mapping);
var response = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as GetCRResponse;
```

> The SoapReflectionImporter class provides type mappings to
>   SOAP-encoded message parts, as defined in a Web Services Description
>   Language (WSDL) document. It is used only when a Web service or client
>   specifies SOAP encoding, as described in Section 5 of the SOAP 1.1
>   specification.

The following command was used to generate your client contracts from WSDL

```
SvcUtil.exe IPlotiservice.wsdl /t:code /serviceContract
```

Comment: Yes I added a post with the DataContractSerializer problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43741674/how-to-use-the-datacontractserializer-to-deserialize-a-wcf-soap-response-message