# How to deserialize a WCF soap message into a generated class

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, deserialization, xml-deserialization

Soap Response message:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="urn:stef">
   <soap:Body>
      <tns:ConvertResponse>
         <tns:Result>abc</tns:Result>
      </tns:ConvertResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Generated code, which is generated by VS when adding a service-reference (*snippet*) :

```cs
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "ConvertResponse", WrapperNamespace = "urn:stef", IsWrapped = true)]
public partial class ConvertResponse
{

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "urn:stef", Order = 0)]
    public string Result;

    public ConvertResponse()
    {
    }

    public ConvertResponse(string Result)
    {
        this.Result = Result;
    }
}
```

I used the following generic code to deserialize this soap string into the `ConvertResponse` object:

```cs
private static T Deserialize<T>(string xml)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml));
    var message = Message.CreateMessage(XmlReader.Create(stream), int.MaxValue, MessageVersion.Soap11);
    var importer = new SoapReflectionImporter(new SoapAttributeOverrides(), "urn:stef");
    var mapping = importer.ImportTypeMapping(typeof(T));
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(mapping);

    return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(message.GetReaderAtBodyContents());
}
```

The solution above is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/43901543/17218587

But this does not work because the `ConvertResponse` class does not have a **public** property for `Result`, so that's the reason `Result` is null after deserialization.

So my question is if there is a way to deserialize this xml-soap message into that (generated) class?

Comment: You can try to parse the XML into an object instance of type ConvertResponse.See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43901543/17218587) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the info, however I based my solution also on that answer. (The link in my post was actually the wrong one, I did correct this). Note that the issue is that the missing public property.

Comment: Why are you manually deserializing rather than using WCF's formatter to do it for you? This is the entire purpose of adding a Service Reference.

Comment: I want to validate if the generated c# code can actually parse the soap xml which returned by the external service. Purpose is mainly unit-testing.
(I had some problems were the generated code using .NET 4.8 was different then 4.7)